# What is a term for iterating over many functions with the same input?

Tags: naming

When we call the same function on a list of things, we call that "map".  What do we call it when we call a list of functions on the same data?  I don't mean pipe - not feeding the output of each function in turn into the next function - but simply iterating over a list of functions, passing each the same input?

Comment: In my day, we used to call that "calling a list of functions with the same input."

Comment: I think calling "collection" of different methods with same signature(input) is what event and eventhandlers does. When you raise an event all eventhandlers executed with same input parameters. I think "delegating" is ok word.

Comment: Using [Flynn's taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn%27s_taxonomy), I would suggest [MISD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISD) (multiple instruction, single data).

Comment: This is a fairly easy example of the Visitor pattern -- maybe you'll find your verbiage researching that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not know of any term for your operation, but it can be seen as a kind of mapping, so maybe you do not need a special name for it. I will illustrate this in Haskell, but it is easy to do the same in other languages, e.g. Python, Clojure, Javascript, etc.

In Haskell `map` has type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

For example, you can map `length` over a list strings:

```
xs = ["Good", "morning", "world"] :: [String]

> map length xs
[4,7,5]
```

Now suppose you have a list of functions, e.g.

```
fs = [(+ 1), (* 5), (* 2)] :: [Int -> Int]
```

How can you apply each function to the same number, say, `1`? You can use the function:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

This function takes another function and applies it to an argument. If you partially apply it to the number `1`, you get:

```
($ 1) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b
```

This is a function that given a function from a numeric type to any type b, applies it to `1`. So, now we can map `($ 1)` over our list of functions:

```
> map ($ 1) fs
[2,5,2]
```

So, in general, given an input `x :: a` and a list of functions `fs :: [a -> b]` you can apply all the functions to `x` with `map ($ x) fs`, which gives you a result of type `[b]`.

Comment: Excellent.  I suspected it was just another variation on `map`, but couldn't articulate an answer well enough to prove it.